# How to deploy a Rack-based Ruby application with Apache 2 and Passenger?

Tags: ruby, apache2, passenger, rack

I have written a very simple "hello world" ruby script which I want to run under apache2 (2.4) and passenger on Ubuntu 14.04. This is not a rails app and I don't want to use the rails framework, this is just a single page application.

So far, all I can get is a directory listing. Here are my files.

uptime.rb

```
class Uptime
  def call(env)
     [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["Hello world!"]]
  end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rack', '~>1.5.1'
```

config.ru

```
require './uptime'
run Uptime.new
```

/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so
```

/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /home/mark/.rbenv/shims/ruby
</IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    PassengerRuby /home/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby      

    <Directory /var/www/html>
      PassengerEnabled on
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I thought the public directory was /var/www/html. This is where my files are.

Comment: That worked, can you write it up as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passenger expects that your app has a `public` and a `tmp` directory:

- The `public` directory has to be your `DocumentRoot`. It will be served by Apache if Passenger is disabled / not working, so nobody can see your application's source code.
- The `tmp` directory is used for Passenger's `restart.txt`.

Your directory tree should look like this:

```
/var/www/html/
├── config.ru
├── uptime.rb
├── Gemfile
├── public/
└── tmp/
```

In your config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    # ...

    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        # ...
    </Directory>

    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```